# Is it possible to create a bubble map in RStudio based on simple dataframe information?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe with every `country` and `infection rates`:

```
country infection
Sweden  1332 
Norway  24
USA     24224 
UK      53534
```

Is there a way to obtain a simple world map and on that plot bubbles on each country that vary in size depending on the infection rate proportions? E.g. in this case the UK would have the largest bubble and Norway the smallest.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you <stackoverflow.com/questions/50201048/…>. Showing how to do exactly what you are asking for!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with `ggplot2` and the wonderful `ggh4x` package by [@teunbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

WorldMap <- map_data("world") %>%
               filter(region != "Antarctica") %>%
               fortify

WorldData <- left_join(WorldData,data, by = c("region" = "country"))

ggplot(WorldData, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +  
  geom_polygon(color="black", fill="white") +
  stat_centroid(data = subset(WorldData, region %in% data$country),
                aes(size = infection, group = region),
                geom = "point",
                alpha = 0.75, color = "red")
```

[image]

The reason the point for the US is in a strange place is because of Alaska and all of the non-continental territories. Good luck fixing that.

Comment: in principle very good! Unfortunately `remotes::install_github("teunbrand/ggh4x")` does not work with the error `Error: Failed to install 'ggh4x' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package`. Do you know how to fix?

Comment: It's now available on CRAN :)